# Where Case Statement trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case, exists

I have a sql server 2008 table, let's say "alpha", with three columns. They are [ID], [col1] and [col2].

```
id|col1|col2
1 |X   |john1X|
1 |Y   |john1Y|
1 |Z   |john1Z|
2 |X   |john2|
3 |Y   |john3|
4 |X   |john4|
```

Each ID might have multiple entries. If col1 contains 'X', I would like that row displayed. If there is no ID with 'X' in col1, I would like 'Y' chosen. Otherwise the row should not come up at all.

For the above sample data, the expected output would be below.

```
id|col1|col2
1 |X   |john1X|
2 |X   |john2|
3 |Y   |john3|
4 |X   |john4|
```

I've been trying to get this code to work,

```
select * from alpha
where col1 = case
             when exists(select * from alpha where col1 = 'X') then 'X'
             else 'Y'
             end
```

however I keep getting the below output no matter how I rewrite the code.

```
id|col1|col2
1 |X   |john1X
2 |X   |john2 
4 |X   |john4
```

Comment: pass id also to your subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a clause in your subquery...  The line

```
 when exists(select * from alpha where col1 = 'X') then 'X'
```

should be

```
when exists(select * from alpha b where col1 = 'X' and b.id = alpha.id ) then 'X'
```

Note that I added an alias to the table in your subquery so that you can match against the ID fields of the subquery's table with the main table.

Comment: Thanks, that's what was missing in my query!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by col1
                               ) as seqnum
      from alpha
      where col1 in ('X', 'Y')
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  this particular logic works as specified because 'X' < 'Y'.  You can use a `case` statement for more general ordering or more values.